# Printing final list in variable

Tags: python, list, python-3.10

I'm working my way through Elements of Programming Interview in Python and I'm trying to find an alternative solution for the first problem in the Arrays chapter.
The idea is that you are to write a program that takes an array A and index i into A and rearranges the elements such that all elements less than A[i] appear first, followed by elements equal to the pivot followed by elements greater than the pivot. In the book, they already provided a solution but I'm trying to figure out an alternative one. In a nutshell, I'm creating subarrays for each aspect such as smaller, equal, and larger than A[i]. For right now I'm working on storing the integer values of A that are less than the pivot. I want to iterate over the list of A and store the values of all elements less than the pivot in the smaller (variable). The idea is to eventually return the variable smaller which will contain all values smaller than the pivot. To check my work I used the print function just to check the value of smaller. It stored each iteration smaller than the pivot in that variable. Ideally using this approach I just want to return the final iteration of the smaller variable instead of each iteration. What should be my next steps? Hopefully, that makes sense, I really don't mind elaborating on any part. Thanks in advance.

```
def properArray(pivot_index, A):
    pivot = A[pivot_index]
    smaller = []
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] < pivot:
            smaller.append(A[i])
            print (smaller)

resized_array =properArray
resized_array(3, [1,5,6,9,3,4,6])
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, just dedent the `print` so it happens only once after the loop is complete.

Comment: You should probably have the function return `smaller` at the end, then use `print(resized_array(...))`

Comment: @0x5453 that's exactly it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are trying to achieve

```
def properArray(pivot_index, A):
     pivot = A[pivot_index]
     smaller = []
     for i in range(len(A)):
         if A[i] < pivot:
             smaller.append(A[i])
     print (smaller)

resized_array =properArray
resized_array(3, [1,5,6,9,3,4,6])
```

Instead of printing `smaller` array on every iteration, you need to print it once, after the for loop is complete

Comment: This is exactly it thanks I'm curious would you be able to explain the purpose of the dedent of the print function. Furthermore, why does it work in this instance

Comment: @Don_de.coder Whitespace matters in python.  If the `print` is indented, it will be inside the loop body, so it will execute on each iteration of the loop.  If it is dedented, it will be outside the loop body and will only execute once after the loop is complete.